# How can a session cookie from Flask-0.10 be deserialized manually?

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask

I have the raw value of a session cookie from a Flask-0.10 application.  I need to read the session in another application that is not using Flask, so I don't have access to the `session` proxy.

In Flask-0.9 I could do the following:

```
session = SecureCookieSession.unserialize(cookie, app.secret_key)
```

However, this method no longer exists in Flask-0.10.  How can I read the cookie data now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask-0.10 switched to [itsdangerous](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com) for serializing the session.  See the [relevant source code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/sessions.py#L297-L310) for how the session is read in Flask.

If you have a session serialized by Flask's default session interface, you can read it manually as follows.

Assuming your secret key is `'dev'`, the session data `{'hello': 'world'}` is serialized to 
`'eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIn0.BwEv5w.o3gYYutryNy7di1E3LbJZbCFGfY'`.

```
from hashlib import sha1
from flask.sessions import session_json_serializer
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer

s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(
    'dev', salt='cookie-session',
    serializer=session_json_serializer,
    signer_kwargs={'key_derivation': 'hmac', 'digest_method': sha1}
)
session_data = s.loads('eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIn0.BwEv5w.o3gYYutryNy7di1E3LbJZbCFGfY')
assert session_data['hello'] == 'world'  # True
```